# What type of Eclipse 4 customization should I choose - Application or Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, customization

I would like to create an Eclipse 4 customization, but I'm new to this aspect of Eclipse development.

As a result, I would like to ask the community what they would recommend based on the following requirements for an SDK-style custom component/project:

- show up as a new project type with it's own Wizard
- the wizard may use some of the built-in java source/path dialogs, but would also provide some custom dialogs of its own
- based on the user selection, the wizard would generate starter code from some template(s)
- once the project has been created, it will be similar to a Java project.  IN FACT, I would like to allow someone the ability to compile select java code into different jars if they want - all within this one project
- finally, when in these new project types inside the project explorer, I need to be able to execute custom commands (with UI support) - such as "Prepare Custom Extension", which will create JARs (if applicable) and copy all relevant source/folders into a prep location, then zip it up

Thanks and let me know if I need to clarify anything!
Bob

Comment: What is an application?  Are you talking about a rich client platform (RCP) application?

Comment: That's a good question.  From what little I've read, yes, I believe RCP is the proper term.  From looking a little further into this, I don't believe an custom RCP is right.  I'm not looking for a complete IDE experience for a user.  I just want to provide a custom project type - along with custom dialogs for project creation, templated code used for file generation based on user input, as well as some additional commands once the project has been created.

Comment: I agree.  You're looking to build an Eclipse plug-in that will extend the functionality of the Eclipse IDE.  The Eclipse for RCP developers would contain all the necessary components to build an Eclipse plug-in.  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junosr1

Comment: can I simply add the required components into an existing Juno JEE environment? or do I have to run a separate workspace/Juno environment?  thx again

Comment: You could put the plug-in components into a Juno JEE Eclipse, but this action could ruin your Eclipse for JEE.  I recommend a separate RCP Eclipse and a separate workspace for your plug-in project.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, thanks!